# logback included logger does not work

Tags: logging, logback

I use logback SLF4J as logging framework in a web application and I want to separate different logic module to different logback configuration file and included them in the central configuration file. so I got a `logback-spring.xml` and `logback.xml` (Central),the `logback-spring.xml` is:

```
<included>
   <logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" level="INFO" additivity="false">
     <appender-ref ref="REST" />
   </logger>

   <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="REST" />
   </logger>
</included>
```

and `logback.xml` is:

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds"> 
<contextName>TestSuite</contextName>

<property scope="context" resource="properties/logback.properties" />


<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">  
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">  
        <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{80} [%file:%line] - %msg%n</Pattern>  
    </encoder>  
</appender>  

<appender name="REST" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">  
   <File>${LOG_HOME:-${java.io.tmpdir}}/RestApi.txt</File>
   <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">  
        <FileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME:-${java.io.tmpdir}}/%d{yyyy-MM/ww,aux}/RestApi.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</FileNamePattern>  
        <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>  
   </rollingPolicy>  
   <encoder>  
        <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{80} - %msg%n</pattern>  
  </encoder>  
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>  

<include optional="true" resource="logback-spring.xml" />
```

When application start, all logging events are written to the console. I can't figure out what's wrong with my configuration, has anybody encountered this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually we can register a status listener to inspect logback's internal status, so we can find out what's wrong in the configuration file.'Cause of logback just printing its internal status data on the console when  warnings or errors occur during the parsing of the configuration file, we don't know what's going on when logback initialization otherwise.

```
<statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener" />
```

[Logback configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#logback.statusLC)

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure out the problem. The logback.xml and logback-spring.xml located in same directory,but dose not in the root classpath directory, it's under the log direcotry, so when I change the include element's resource attribute to log/logback-spring.xml

```
<include optional="true" resource="log/logback-spring.xml" />
```

It's work perfectly!